# Link properties of object to model

Tags: database, autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit, forge

I am currently working with Forge RCDB and MongoDB. I have a .dwf model (made with Revit), that i exported in a .svf file. I managed to display the model in the viewer, as shown in forge examples (https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/database?id=583ec7efebfb320e3cef26a5 for example).

Now, i also want to display properties (length, area, volume...). I downloaded some forge examples, and it seemes that the properties are saved in .json.gz files. With the data i work on, i'm not sure i can export the properties in a .json file. But i can export it as a .gbXML and ODBC database.

My question is : how exactly are the property files and the model being linked ? Is it even possible with an object from Revit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, here is what I did at the end :

I kept the .rvt model and converted it into .svf with https://extract.autodesk.io . 
In the exported folder, there are several .json.gz files, which contains the properties (objects.attrs.json.gz,objects_ids.json.gz, ...). They are read automatically when displaying the model i think, because i didn't do anything special about them. Now when i use Forge React Boiler and Forge RCDB, I can display my models and their properties.

When i asked my question i was using a model without properties. I chose another one with properties and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: how exactly are the property files and the model being linked? Is it even possible with an object from Revit?

The Forge Viewer uses a SVF format, which is not yet documented, but it's a collection of JSON files. The `viewer3d.js` library takes care of putting together the properties and the respective `threejs` 3D representation. If you need to access the properties, then I would suggest the **[Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2)**, a collection of REST endpoints to retrieve the hierarchy and properties of a model.